# sleep() delaying the whole page in php script

Tags: javascript, php

I want to display the echo for 5 seconds and redirect the page to login.html but when the page loads it takes 5 seconds instead of loading the page and waiting 5 sec then redirect.

```
<?php

  session_start();
  if (isset($_SESSION['name'])) {
      echo $_SESSION['name'];
  } else {
      echo "Login To Order";
      sleep(5);
      echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\">
                window.location.href = \"login.html\"; 
            </script>";
  }

?>
```

EDIT: 
ok this seems to delay it for 5 seconds but the code execution still continues 
further but I want it to stop =>echo for 5 seconds =>redirect to the other page.

```
             echo "Login To Order"; 
             echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\">
                      window.setTimeout(function() {
                              window.location.href=\"login.html\";
                              }, 5000);
                     </script>";
            echo "this should not be displayed";
```

echo "this should not be displayed";
my point here is that I have others codes below that I don't want to be executed in the else case.

Comment: use a timeout in javascript or an interval

Comment: @JaromandaX that code pasted inline might as well be a full answer reply :)

Comment: I decided to post an answer to also show how writing inline HTML doesn't have to be a laborious "echo"

Comment: `echo "this should not be displayed";` - then don't output it!

Comment: my point is that I have others codes below that I don't want to be executed in the else case.

Comment: in that case see my answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PHP pre-processes the page on the server, then sends the page to the client browser - sleeping on the server will rarely equate to a delay on the client

Put the delay on the client side using setTimeout

```
<?php
    session_start(); 
    if (isset($_SESSION['name'])){
        echo $_SESSION['name'];
    } else {
?>
        Login To Order
        <script>
            setTimeout(function() {
                window.location.href="login.html";
            }, 5000);
        </script>
<?php
        exit(0);
    }
?>
```

note how you can switch PHP preprocessing off `?>` to make the script easier to write, then switch PHP back on `<?php`

or even simpler, use a HTTP header to do the work for you

```
<?php
    session_start(); 
    if (isset($_SESSION['name'])){
        echo $_SESSION['name'];
    } else {
        header("refresh:5; url=login.html"); 
?>
        Login To Order
<?php
        exit(0);
    }
?>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I have used your javascript code and it worked.

Answer (score 2):

**[`sleep()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sleep.php)** is processed by the **server**, before the DOM is rendered.

To redirect to another page after 5 seconds, you could always use the `refresh` parameter of PHP's **[`header()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php)**:

```
header("refresh:5; url=login.html");
```

However, considering you also want to display **output** before the user gets redirected, you probably will want to use a **[`setTimeout()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout)** in the JavaScript:

```
window.setTimeout(function() {
  window.location.href=\"login.html\";
}, 5000);
```

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: is 5000 the seconds of delay?

Comment: see javascript documentation for setTimeout ... hint: it's milliseconds

Comment: @LulGate - your edit makes no sense, if you don't want `this should not be displayed` in the page, then don't `echo "this should not be displayed";`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using PHP use Javascript to do what you want.

Here is a sample

```
<?php

  session_start();
  if (isset($_SESSION['name'])) {
      echo $_SESSION['name'];
  } else {
      echo "Login To Order";
      echo '<script>setTimeout(function(){ window.location.replace("http://stackoverflow.com"); }, 5000);</script>';
      return;
      /*other codes*/
  }

?>
```